# QtDesigner custom widget dll blocked by QtCreator

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator, qt-designer

I have a project, maintained in QtCreator, where one of the elements is a QtDesigner plugin (custom widget). The problem is, QtCreator is blocking this plugin (dll file) and I can't build the whole project - I can't even run it, as qmake knows there was an error (while copying the dll) and doesn't allow to run the final exe.
What can I do about it? Maybe there's a way to force QtCreator to unload the plugin? Or maybe there's a rule to allow the project to run, if the fail was only because of this?

Windows 7, Qt 5.3.2, x64, MSVC2013, QtCreator 3.3.2 built from sources (for x64).